# Regex Expression Only Numbers and Characters

Tags: c#, wpf, regex

I created the following regex expression for my C# file. Bascily I want the user's input to only be regular characters (A-Z lower or upper) and numbers. (spaces or symbols ).

[a-zA-Z0-9]

For some reason it only fails when its a symbol on its own. if theres characters mixed with it then the expression passes.

I can show you my code of how I implment it but I think its my expression.

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you forgot about the plus? [a-zA-Z0-9]+

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that it can match *anywhere*. You need anchors:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]+\z
```

`^` matches the start of a string, and `\z` matches the end of a string.

(Note: in .NET regex, `$` matches the end of a string with an optional newline.)

Comment: Awesome thats what it was Thanks!

Comment: i know you already answered my question but now im trying to make the first character uppercase. I tried this which i found on the internet but it doesnt seem to work when use uppercase input: ^[A-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]+$

Comment: It looks fine... are you entering one uppercase letter? It should be `^[A-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$` instead.

Comment: @hungdoan: Almost, but not quite: `\w` includes the underscore, `_`. I suppose it could be `[^\W_]`, but I think it gets less clear at that point. (In addition to that, in .NET, `\w` matches all Unicode letters and digits, not just ASCII ones, which doesn’t seem to be what the question is asking for.)

Answer (score 4):

This is because it will match any character in the string you need the following.
Forces it to match the entire string not just part of it

```
^[0-9a-zA-Z]*$
```

Answer (score 3):

That regex will match every single alphanumeric character in the string as separate matches.

If you want to make sure the whole string the user entered only has alphanumeric characters you need to do something like:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you making sure to check the whole string? That is are you using an expression like
`^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$`
where `^` means the start of the string and `$` means the end of the string?